# Why I am getting this syntax error on making an atom "band"?

Tags: erlang, syntax-error, reserved-words

```erlang
1> Band = band.
* 1: syntax error before: 'band'
```

I am trying to make an atom here, but I am getting a syntax error. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear from the compiler error but you are getting but this due to the fact that you are using a *reserved word*. There is a [complete list here](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.8/doc/reference_manual/introduction.html).

> after and andalso band begin bnot bor bsl bsr bxor case catch cond div end fun if let not of or orelse query receive rem try when xor

`band` is an operator for "binary and".

You can use single quotes for atoms that can't be used directly.

```erlang
1> Band = 'band'.
'band'
```